# Initializing an indeterminate checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, checkbox

I need to create an [inderterminate checkbox](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/indeterminate/#article-header-id-0) which starts with the indeterminate status.

to do this I created a checkbox in my HTML

```
<div *ngIf="item.CanSearch && item.SearchType === 'Bool'"><input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox"  name="insideListResourceIdsCB" (click)="indeterminateCheckbox($event.target)" /></div>
```

when you click the checkbox this function get's called (this part works without any problems)

```
/* function to create an indeterminate checkbox*/
public indeterminateCheckbox(cb) {       
    if (cb.readOnly) {
        cb.checked = cb.readOnly = false;
        this.insideListResourceIds = false;
    }
    else if (!cb.checked) {
        cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
        this.insideListResourceIds = null;
    } else if (cb.checked) {
        this.insideListResourceIds = true;
    }
    this.getEmployeesOverview();
}
```

However the problem comes when I load my view. The checbox needs to have the visual state of indeterminate, this is only possible via javascript. To do this I've created this function:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let checkbox = <any>$("#my-checkbox");
        checkbox.indeterminate = true;
}
```

however everytime I load my view, my checkbox is empty. I don't receive any errors however, when I `console.log(checkbox)` this is the result:

[image]

*My question is:* How do I correctly set the visual state of the checkbox to `indeterminate` when the view loads?

Comment: assuming you're using angular2, you could use the [indeterminate]=1 attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leverage attribute directive to set `indeteminate`

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=checkbox][indeterminate]'
})
export class IndeterminateDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.indeterminate = true;
  }
}
```

now you can use it like

```
<input type="checkbox" indeterminate ...
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bLOpWdjrKb7ePHN10Jj3?p=preview)**

And second approach could be just using property binding like

```
[indeterminate]="true"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/at7CVORmyDytax3Im4GA?p=preview)**

Comment: wow I didn't even know `[indeterminate]="true"` was possible! something so simple, thanks!